# Getting invalid password error when logging in with Meteor.loginWithPassword

Tags: meteor

I am using the accounts-password package of the meteor. When try to login, it fails twice and when try the third time, it is logging in successfully.

code for creating user

```
Accounts.createUser({email: email, password : password}, function(err){
    if (err) {
       console.log('The user creation failed.');           
    } else {
       // Success. Account has been created and the user
       // has logged in successfully. 
       console.log('The user has been created.');
    }

});
```

Code for login

```
Meteor.loginWithPassword({email:email}, password, function(err){
    if (err) {
        console.log('login failed');
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log('login success');
    }
});
```

I am getting "Incorrect password [403]" error when try to login.

I dont understand what the issue is. Please help me how to fix this issue.

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful to know when these calls are happening (I suspect that's your problem). `createUser` should only be called once per user when you are first initializing your database. `loginWithPassword` should be called once everything is loaded, e.g. in response to a DOM event like `submit`.

Comment: I have a registration form and a login form. createUser is called when submitting the registration form and loginWithPassword when submitting the login form.

Comment: Are you sure that the data you are passing to 'loginWithPassword' are correct? Maybe there is a problem somwhere within your form? Does the login procedure fails when you try to call 'loginWithPassword' in the console?

Comment: well, it seems to be working fine now. Do not understand what the problem was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the exact same problem. Every third try it would work. The problem was that I was already authenticated as a user. Once I called Meteor.logout() in the console and logged in, it works on the first try.

Comment: that exactly is the reason, it seems.